# How to fix Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: typescript, next.js, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I configured all my jest with babael, but I can't run the tests, it always shows the same error.
I'm using nextJs and typescript with styled-components.

FAIL  src/components/Main/main.spec.tsx
● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

C:\teste next\mks-sistemas\public\assets\cartImage.png:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){�PNG


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

  1 | import React from "react";
  2 | import * as S from "./styles";
> 3 | import iconCart from "../../../public/assets/cartImage.png";
    | ^
  4 | import Image from "next/image";
```

Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.841 s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbkVV.png)

I already followed several configuration tutorials but none of them worked, I believe that jest should only do the test in the folder that I set but it is getting errors from other pages with svg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set your jest.config like below and install necessary packages

`npm i jest-environment-jsdom tsconfig-paths-jest`

```js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');
const tsconfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
const moduleNameMapper = require('tsconfig-paths-jest')(tsconfig);

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: './',
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  

  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setupTests.ts'],

  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  bail: true,
  logHeapUsage: true,
  testTimeout: 120000,
  forceExit: true,
  collectCoverage: true,


  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],
  moduleNameMapper,
  
};


module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

Comment: it worked I had not installed jest-environment-jsdom. thanks

Comment: Ok great now you can increase coverage ;)